# Java application not utilizing complete heap memory

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I started my java application with option **-Xmx20G**, so it should be able to use up to 20GB heap memory. I connected jVidualVm and JMC to my application and can see that maximum of only 8GB memory is being used by application.
Once the memory usage reaches around 8GB, garbage collection happens.

Please see the image

[image: Memory usage as seen on JMC, the committed heap memory can be seen as 20GB]

Memory usage as seen on JMC, the max heap memory can be seen as 20GB.

Any ideas why memory usage is not reaching around 20GB, before GC happens?

Comment: show the GC logs - you most probably see minor GC happening

Answer (score 1):

A typical Java heap is divided into a new space and old space.  When the new space fills up, it is garbage collected.  Since "most objects die young", and garbage is "less work" than non-garbage, the new space collector is fast ...

Objects that survive a few new space collections are moved to the old space (the technical term is "tenured").  When the old space starts to fill up, the old space collector is triggered.  The old space collector is slower because the old space is typically larger, objects there tend to survive multiple GCs, and other factors.

So, looking at that graph, it appears that your JVM's new space is ~7GB and its old space is ~14GB.  It looks like your application is generating garbage object steadily, and this is repeatedly triggering the new space collector.  However, it looks like the new space collector is *succeeding* in almost emptying the new space. (Look how low the troughs in the graph ar4e.  It looks like they drop to ~0.5MB.)

So the short answer is that your 20GB heap is not being fully used ... because it doesn't need to be used.  It is over-sized for that application / workload.

Comment: Yes, this looks like the case.
Most of the objects that application was generating were getting from young generation and getting garbage collected with miner GC. For confirmation I increased the size of young generation with flag Xmn14G. Now up to 14G memory is being used.

Having this identified, that most of the memory object in my application are from young generation, should I permanently increase the young generation memory size? Will it increase performance, as less miner GC will happen? Is it good practice?

Comment: Measure it!  My intuition is that the new space is probably large enough that increasing it won't have much benefit.  But the flip-side is that increasing new space may increase GC pauses (because new space collections are STW), and they may result in more paging during GC (because the new GC has to access more pages).  These things could all be application specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding –XX:+DisableExplicitGC to your command line to check if this changes something.

Comment: Tried this flag, but it didn't change anything. Behavior wrt to memory is still same.
I checked the application code, and we are not calling System.gc() anywhere from within the code.

Comment: I suggest using JConsole to take a deeper look at memory usage. It allows to see memory utilization by pool. As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/66983181/12962623 it maybe the case that you just don’t have enough long-lived objects to be kept in the old generation.

Comment: Yes. It looks like that most of the objects that application was generating were from young generation.